# Symfont/Twig FatalErrorException in Twig Core.php line 1595:

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, twig

*Note: This is my first Symfony project, so obvious mistakes are possible.*

I have just pushed my Symfony application from my local environment (where it works nicely) to a live server.  Sadly, after running server:start, if I try and curl one of the local routes in the same way I tested on my local, I get the below error back:

> FatalErrorException in Core.php line 1595: Parse Error: syntax error,
>   unexpected '.'

Note that the Core.php file is /var/www/symfony_playground/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Extension/Core.php

I didn't some searching online, and cannot see anyone else getting similar issues, so wonder whether I have a dependency issue (although I checked this).

The line in twig that is causing the issue looks like:

```
$ret = $object->$method(...$arguments);
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your server is not very up-to-date when it comes to PHP. Variadic functions (the ...$arguments) were introduced in PHP 5.6 so my guess is your server is running an older version than that.

Give it a debug with by echoing [phpversion()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php) or even the more detailed [phpinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php).

If this is the case the only solution would be to update PHP as downgrading symfony doesn't really work.

Comment: This was it, I thought I had symfony 2.8 which worked with 5.3+.  But if that is the issue, then I have php5.5 on a debian wheezy box.  Time for a full os upgrade I think.